# WebApi EntitySetController using composite keys

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-odata

The excellent sample code: [Support Composite Key in ASP.NET Web API OData](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Support-Composite-Key-in-d1d53161)
illustrates how to create routing conventions to make WebApi OData work with composite keys.

However it is using ODataController ([as one of the unanswered discussions on the sample code mentions](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Support-Composite-Key-in-d1d53161/view/Discussions#content)) which I presume has many downsides (which I am yet to fully uncover)... has anyone created an example using the benefits of EntitySetController?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going forward the recommended approach is to directly derive from `ODataController`. Visual Studio 2013 provides scaffolding for creating OData services based on ODataController. This has been found to be a much more flexible model than deriving from EntitySetController. You get complete control over what is done in your actions.

Comment: Thanks Kiran, that's very interesting, do you have any recommended articles?